# Is there a way to trigger a hardware refresh (aka Device Manager) using .NET?

Tags: .net, api, hardware, device-manager

I don't mind if it's only possible in the latest version of Windows, but I am wondering if there is a way to trigger this using .NET:

[Device Manager Hardware Refresh http://imgbag.com/josh/joshx/StackOverflow/devicemanager.png?p=Rectangle(130,430,270,100,10,Yellow)](http://imgbag.com/josh/joshx/StackOverflow/devicemanager.png?p=Rectangle(130,430,270,100,10,Yellow))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found this piece of code which could help to point you in the right direction. You will need to add the windows api to your project and mimic this:

```
#INCLUDE "Win32Api.inc"
DECLARE FUNCTION fCM_Locate_DevNode (BYREF dvInst AS LONG, BYVAL n AS LONG, BYVAL c AS LONG) AS LONG
DECLARE FUNCTION fCM_Reenumerate_DevNode (BYVAL dvInst AS LONG, BYVAL n AS LONG) AS LONG

FUNCTION Scan_for_hardware_changes () AS LONG

    %CR_SUCCESS = 0
    %CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL = 0

    LOCAL hLib AS LONG, pCM_DevNode AS DWORD, fSTATUS AS LONG, dvInst AS LONG

    hLib = LoadLibrary( "cfgmgr32.dll" )
    IF hLib THEN
        pCM_DevNode = GetProcAddress( hLib, "CM_Locate_DevNodeA" )
        IF pCM_DevNode THEN
            CALL DWORD pCM_DevNode USING fCM_Locate_DevNode(dvInst, 0, %CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL ) TO fSTATUS
            IF fSTATUS=%CR_SUCCESS THEN
                pCM_DevNode = GetProcAddress( hLib, "CM_Reenumerate_DevNode" )
                IF pCM_DevNode THEN
                    CALL DWORD pCM_DevNode USING fCM_Reenumerate_DevNode(dvInst, 0 ) TO fSTATUS
                    IF fSTATUS=%CR_SUCCESS THEN FUNCTION=%TRUE
                END IF
            END IF
        END IF
        FreeLibrary hLib
    END IF

END FUNCTION

FUNCTION PBMAIN

  IF Scan_for_hardware_changes() THEN MSGBOX "OK!" ELSE MSGBOX "Sorry!"

END FUNCTION
```

Comment: You will find http://pinvoke.net/ to be of great use in figuring out how to define the Win API functions in your .net code.